# Count successful HTTP Requests in "bzm - Parallel Controller"

Tags: jmeter

How to count successful HTTP Requests in "bzm - Parallel Controller". Have tried __counter() function in "BeanShell PostProcessor" with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

1. Tick `Generate parent sample` in the "bzm - Parallel Controller"
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) after the "bzm - Parallel Controller"
3. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def successful = 0
   ctx.getPreviousResult().getSubResults().each { subResult ->
       if (subResult.isSuccessful()) {
           successful++
       }
   }
   vars.put('successful', successful as String)
   ```

   where:

   - `ctx` - is a shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
   - `vars` - is an instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
4. You will be able to refer the number of successful samplers as `${successful}` or `${__V(successful)}` where required.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.